# JAVA 8 pass return value back into same method x number of times

Tags: java, functional-programming, refactoring

I have this code which I want to refactor using a functional style, using Java 8. I would like to remove the mutable object currentRequest and still return the filtered request.

```
    HttpRequest currentRequest = httpRequest;
    for (Filter filter : filters) {
        currentRequest = filter.doFilter(currentRequest);
    }
```

The aim is to pass a request to the filter.doFilter method, and take the output and pass it back into the filter.doFilter method, and continue to do this until all filters are applied.

For example in a more convoluted way to the for loop

```
    HttpRequest filteredRequest1 = filters.get(0).doFilter(currentRequest);
    HttpRequest filteredRequest2 = filters.get(1).doFilter(filteredRequest1);
    HttpRequest filteredRequest3 = filters.get(2).doFilter(filteredRequest2);
    ...
```

I think this is a case for **composing functions**, and the doFilter method should be a function like below:

```
    Function<HttpRequest, HttpRequest> applyFilter = request -> filters.get(0).doFilter(request);
```

But I know this is totally wrong, as I got stuck here.

The other way I was thinking was to use **reduce**, but I cannot see a way of using it in this case.

If you could help me out with a way of doing this, or point me to some resource that will be great.

Comment: "*I would like to remove the mutable object currentRequest ...*" - Are you talking about the object referenced by `currentRequest` or the reference `currentRequest`? The first is only achieveable (provided, `HttpRequest` is a mutable object), if you rewrite `HttpRequest`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you may want to do a `reduce` with your `HttpRequest` as its identity.  Each step of the reduce will combine the intermediate result with the next filter, like so:

```
filters.stream().reduce(currentRequest,
                        (req, filter) -> filter.doFilter(req),
                        (req1, req2) -> throwAnExceptionAsWeShouldntBeHere());
```

Note: the last function is used to merge two `HttpRequests` together if a parallel stream is used.  If that's the route you wish to go down, then proceed with caution.

Comment: is `currentRequest` *really* an identity? I wonder if this would work for parallel processing, still good idea! 1+

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way that streams the filters and maps each one of them to a `UnaryOperator<HttpRequest>`. Then, all the functions are [reduced](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) via the [`Function.andThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#andThen-java.util.function.Function-) operator and finally, if the `filters` collections wasn't empty, the resulting composed function is executed with the `currentRequest` as an argument:

```
HttpRequest result = filters.stream()
    .map(filter -> ((Function<HttpRequest, HttpRequest>) filter::doFilter))
    .reduce(Function::andThen)
    .map(function -> function.apply(currentRequest))
    .orElse(currentRequest);
```

Comment: In order for that to compile, that `ifPresent` will want to be `.map(function -> function.apply(currentRequest)).orElse(currentRequest)`

Comment: @JoeC true. Thanks for the catch